# Convertir un Json a un objeto

Tags: flutter, dart, aplicación-movil

Se tiene esta respuesta (JSON) del servidor:

```
{
"status": "success",
"message": "",
"data": [
    {
        "idCanasta": 110,
        "idOrden": 110,
        "idTipoOrden": 2,
        "idTipoPago": 1,
        "idNegocio": 0,
        "nombreComercial": "Tacoos El Sumidero",
        "fotoNegocio": null,
        "telefono": "9611774990",
        "idUsuario": 0,
        "nombreUsuario": "Luis Medina Velázquez",
        "fotoUsuario": "Foto-perfil-principal.png",
        "celular": "+529611774989",
        "fecha": "2020-09-27T20:53:11",
        "fechaString": null,
        "artilulos": null,
        "subtotal": 0.0,
        "envio": 0.0,
        "total": 54.00,
        "idEstatus": 1,
        "estatus": "Esperando ser aceptada"
    },]
}
```

y se tiene este par de objetos:

```html
class Business {
  final String status;
  final String message;
  final BusinessData data;

  Business(this.status, this.message, this.data);

  Business.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : status = json['status'],
        message = json['message'],
        data = json['data'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
    {
       'status':status,
       'message':message,
       'data':data};

}
```

```html
class BusinessData {
  final int idNegocio;
  final int idCategoriaNegocio;
  final String token;
  final String razonSocial;
  final String nombreComercial;
  final String slogan;
  final String descripcion;
  final String rfc;
  final String celular;
  final String telefono;
  final int idEstatus;
  final String estatus;
  final String correo;
  final String fotoNegocio;
  final String direccion;
  final int idMunicipio;
  final int idEstado;
  final String municipio;
  final String estado;
  final String latitud;
  final String longitud;
  final String nombre;
  final String apellidos;
  final String celularRep;
  final int idBanco;
  final String cuenta;
  final String tarjeta;
  final String beneficiario;
  final String url;

  final String abre;
  final String cierra;
  final int estatusHorario;
  final int abreHoy;
  final int favorito;
  final int calificacion;
  final int tiempoEntrega;
  final int tiempoMaximoEntrega;
  final int aceptandoOrdenes;
  final List <CategoryProduct> categorias;
  final List <Permisos> permisos;

  BusinessData(this.idNegocio,
               this.idCategoriaNegocio,
               this.token,
               this.razonSocial,
               this.nombreComercial,
               this.slogan,
               this.descripcion,
               this.rfc,
               this.celular,
               this.telefono,
               this.idEstatus,
               this.estatus,
               this.correo,
               this.fotoNegocio,
               this.direccion,
               this.idMunicipio,
               this.idEstado,
               this.municipio,
               this.estado,
               this.latitud,
               this.longitud,
               this.nombre,
               this.apellidos,
               this.celularRep,
               this.idBanco,
               this.cuenta,
               this.tarjeta,
               this.beneficiario,
               this.url,
               this.abre,
               this.cierra,
               this.estatusHorario,
               this.abreHoy,
               this.favorito,
               this.calificacion,
               this.tiempoEntrega,
               this.tiempoMaximoEntrega,
               this.aceptandoOrdenes,
               this.categorias,
               this.permisos);

  BusinessData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : idNegocio = json['idNegocio'],
        idCategoriaNegocio = json['idCategoriaNegocio'],
        token = json['token'],
        razonSocial = json['razonSocial'],
        nombreComercial = json['nombreComercial'],
        slogan = json['slogan'],
        descripcion = json['descripcion'],
        rfc = json['rfc'],
        celular = json['celular'],
        telefono = json['telefono'],
        idEstatus = json['idEstatus'],
        estatus = json['estatus'],
        correo = json['correo'],
        fotoNegocio = json['fotoNegocio'],
        direccion = json['direccion'],
        idMunicipio = json['idMunicipio'],
        idEstado = json['idEstado'],
        municipio = json['municipio'],
        estado = json['estado'],
        latitud = json['latitud'],
        longitud = json['longitud'],
        nombre = json['nombre'],
        apellidos = json['apellidos'],
        celularRep = json['celularRep'],
        idBanco = json['idBanco'],
        cuenta = json['cuenta'],
        tarjeta = json['tarjeta'],
        beneficiario = json['beneficiario'],
        url = json['url'],
        abre = json['abre'],
        cierra = json['cierra'],
        estatusHorario = json['estatusHorario'],
        abreHoy = json['abreHoy'],
        favorito = json['favorito'],
        calificacion = json['calificacion'],
        tiempoEntrega = json['tiempoEntrega'],
        tiempoMaximoEntrega = json['tiempoMaximoEntrega'],
        aceptandoOrdenes = json['aceptandoOrdenes'],
        categorias = json['categorias'],
        permisos = json['permisos'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
    {
       'idNegocio':idNegocio,
       'idCategoriaNegocio':idCategoriaNegocio,
       'token':token,
       'razonSocial':razonSocial,
       'nombreComercial':nombreComercial,
       'slogan': slogan,
       'descripcion':descripcion,
        'rfc': rfc,
        'celular': celular,
        'telefono': telefono,
        'idEstatus': idEstatus,
        'estatus': estatus,
        'correo': correo,
        'fotoNegocio': fotoNegocio,
        'direccion': direccion,
        'idMunicipio': idMunicipio,
        'idEstado': idEstado,
        'municipio': municipio,
        'estado': estado,
        'latitud': latitud,
        'longitud': longitud,
        'nombre': nombre,
        'apellidos': apellidos,
        'celularRep': celularRep,
        'idBanco': idBanco,
        'cuenta': cuenta,
        'tarjeta': tarjeta,
        'beneficiario': beneficiario,
        'url': url,
        'abre': abre,
        'cierra': cierra,
        'estatusHorario': estatusHorario,
        'abreHoy': abreHoy,
        'favorito': favorito,
        'calificacion':calificacion,
        'tiempoEntrega': tiempoEntrega,
        'tiempoMaximoEntrega':tiempoMaximoEntrega,
        'aceptandoOrdenes': aceptandoOrdenes,
        'categorias': categorias,
        'permisos': permisos
    };

}
```

Se consume la api de esta manera:

```html
getOrdenBusinnes(token , bodye) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer $token',};
   // String cuerpo = '{"idNegocio": 2}';
    try {
      Response response =
      await post('https://pideexpress.com.mx/api/business/ordenesnegocio', headers: headers, body:bodye);
      int statusCode = response.statusCode;
      String body = response.body;
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        String responseJson = response.body.toString();
        final List<String> data = [];
        Map userMap = jsonDecode(responseJson);
        for (var item in userMap['data']) {

          Map userMap = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(item));
          var orderdata = OrdersData.fromJson(userMap);

        }


        return responseJson;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    } on Exception catch (exception) {
        return false;
    }    
 }
```

El codigo anterior me da una exception, diciendome que la lista no puede ser de tipo dynamica.

Ya he tratado de muchas maneras que he visto en la red, pero ninguna me funciona, Por favor si me pueden orientar, estoy desesperada, <3,

Comment: que retorna este método ? getOrdenBusinnes , veo que tienes un return false, pero tambien un responseJson ? tendrías que retornar el mismo tipo de dato, también agrega en que parte/linea te marca el error y quien llama a getOrdenBusinnes

Comment: se puede ignorar que regresa la funcion, se puso para estar en contexto, el detalle esta en como convertir el JSON que retorna la API a el objeto que tengo.

Comment: OrdersData.fromJson(item) es todo

Comment: hice lo que me comento y aun no :(

Answer (score 1):

Te corrijo la parte del parsing, suponiendo que la data del server es correcta y obtienes el `String` en `responseJson`.

```dart
    String responseJson = jsonEncode(data);
    Map userMap = jsonDecode(responseJson);
    final list = userMap['data'];
    final result = <BusinessData>[];
    for (var item in list) {
      var orderdata = BusinessData.fromJson(item);
      result.add(orderdata);
    }

    //comprobando
    for (BusinessData item in result) {
      print(item.toJson());
    }
```

OJO: vi que estabas usando `OrdersData` , pero tu clase es `BusinessData`.